# Помогите "завести карусель" - никак не выходит

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет! В интернет-магазине в корзину должны помещаться товары и выводится в карусели. Как добавить товары из корзины в слайдер я нашел, а вот как заставить его вращаться после реинициализации - загадка..В коде для крутелок показывает display:none; - значит слайдер не хочет, чтобы его вращали. Такой вывод я сделал, т.к. по аналогии, если из содержимого owl-carousel убрать пустой div,  то карусель вообще пытается скрыться от глаз долой - прячется в display:none и opacity:0; Может быть найдутся умные люди, кто сможет мне помочь в этом вопросе - буду премного благодарен!

отредактированный вопрос: при первой попытке добавить товар в дополнительной корзине выводится пустое поле с надписью "корзина пуста", при втором клике на кнопку добавить пустое поле удаляется и больше ничего не выводится, а уже при 3ем выводится товар как и положено, но он только 3ий товар показывает из корзины, а первые 2 видны только в основной..

```js
$('#foot-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items: 3,
  navigation: true,
  navigationText: ["", ""],
});

$(".add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
  $("#foot-carousel div:contains('Корзина пуста.')").remove();

  $('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div>' + $('.cart_list li:last').html() + '</div>');
  $(".fixed-bottom").show().fadeTo("slow");
});
```

```html
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
  <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget ">
    <!-- сюда выводятся товары помещаемые в корзину -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="foot-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <!-- здесь формируется карусель -->
  </div>
</div>
```

---

карусель завелась, то товар отправляется в нее только с 3ей попытки, т.е. первых двух товаров в корзине не видно.. что не так по условию или не хватает какой-то проверки?

Comment: хмм.. карусель оказывается заработала, но почему-то для одного вида товаров, т.е. если положил 3 одинаковых товара, то она срабатывает.. очень странное поведение, но не то, что мне нужно

Answer (score 1):

Продублирую:
Вам нужно добавлять слайды через встроенный метод:

```
owl.addItem(htmlString [,targetPosition])
```

[источник](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing)

Сам я не пользовался этим слайдером, но советую всегда читать мануалы, скорее всего там вы найдете ответ.

Comment: насколько я понял targetPosition по умолчанию итак равен -1 и его можно не добавлять или что вы имели ввиду?
Second parameter "targetPosition" is optional and accept number values. 
  To add item at the end of carousel you could use -1 value. Last item is default value.
чем строчка:
$('#foot-carousel').data('owlCarousel').addItem('<div>' + $('.cart_list li:last').html() + '</div>');
не устроила?